# Applying for a Schengen visa with UK visa expiring in less than 3 months?

Tags: visas, schengen, uk

I was thinking of visiting some Schengen countries this June. However, my UK visa will be expired on August 30th, 2015. I know that most (or all) of Schengen countries require UK visa to be valid for at least 3 (or 6) months by the time I leave Schengen area. Do you guys think it is worth applying for a Schengen visa anyway or I should forget about it?

Comment: It is too late now. Forget about it, Wasting £75 for a refusal and a stamp on your passport isn't worth it.

Comment: I've never heard of this. It is your passport that needs to be valid. I've never heard of any Schengen country caring how long your visa for some other non-Schengen country is valid for.

Comment: This depends.  Are you relying upon UK residency in order to qualify for a Schengen application?

Comment: @MichaelHampton, come to chat. It is being hashed over by Relaxed and I.